# NVIDIA DRIVERS INSTALLING

Tags: nvidia, graphics, additional-drivers

**I'm sorry from my ignorance but I am completely fresh with using linux UBUNTU.**

**1.So my problem begin from the installation UBUNTU (doesn't matter the version i have tried with 18.04 and 20.04). That was impossible to install system because screen was freeze after few seconds. So I find solution in network:**

*Disable Fast Boot and Secure Boot (or Secure loader).

Plug in the bootable USB with the Linux distro (mine was Ubuntu 16.04)

When you see the loader to "Install Ubuntu" etc ... press "e" and edit a line: Replace "quiet splash" to "nomodeset" and press F10 to boot.

Then after the installation is complete, you will have to reboot. This time you will now encounter the GRUB. Again, press "e" and edit a line: In the line that starts with "linux", add "nouveau.modeset=0" at the end of that line.
Your Linux should now boot.

After this, you need to install the nvidia drivers. Reboot. And then it's done.*
**

**2. Finally I was able to install system. After then I changed GRUB by another instruction:**

*If you require noveau.modeset=0 in order to boot properly, you could add an extra kernel boot parameter in the /etc/default/grub file so that you don't have to type it in (and can continue to use the open source nouveau drivers).

Boot up using your 'safe mode' solution and then open a terminal and use

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

to change
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
to be
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"

(press Ctrl + x to exit, y to confirm saving the changes and Enter to accept the filename)

If you then run `sudo update-grub` to update your changes, when you reboot it should work as if you'd typed that line in yourself each time.*

**3.After this steps everything is almost ok. BUT MY PROBLEM IS THAT I CANT INSTALL NVIDIA DRIVERS. I CAN'T CHANGE ANY GRAPHICS OPTION. SYSTEM DOESN'T SEE MY ADDITIONAL MONITOR (ITS NESESERY TO MY SCHOOL). I have tried to do it manually.**

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia*
```

downolading it from nvidia page and install by:

```
sudo ./"drivers name"
```

**I have tried also do it by PPA but also without result. Its information:

> nvidia drivers are in conflict whith nvidia-dkms-kernel

**After many tries finally I was installed nvidia drivers 440.82 but after reboot it's just black screen.**

**Second problem is that I cant install drivers from: additional drivers in UBUNTU. When I try to find some additional drivers there is empty. Nothing to install.**

Details:
ASUS TUF GAMING, Ryzen 5 4600H, GTX 1650 TI, 16 GB RAM
UBUNTU VERSION: 20.04.

Comment: No drivers found for installation 

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Please try to keep the question concise and integrate any other relevant information into it, not by posting an answer.

Comment: Ok. I try very hard. But Im newbie and I couldnt find a way to add a picture

Answer (score 1):

**Ok. Problem is solved. I used this solution**:

Please follow this:

delete `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

make sure nvidia-prime is installed (`sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-prime`)

switch to nvidia (`sudo prime-select nvidia`)

remove stray blacklist files (`sudo rm /lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf`)

update the initrd (`sudo update-initramfs -u`)

reboot

**But firstly to get into tty1 to change
  the GRUB instruction from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"` by

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Glad you found @GIX2000

Comment: Please update your answer by mentioning how did you install the driver in the first place.

Comment: This means you've  added wrong settings then heroically found then and removed. There was no ` blacklist-nvidia.conf` initially and there was no `xorg.conf`.

Answer (score -1):

I personally recommend you follow this. This is absolutely a time saver for installing these graphics drivers.

Source of this info: [here](https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/df039f0dc434d6486f5d4d098aa52d07)

**Install NVIDIA Graphics Driver via runfile**

Initially remove all the previous Nvidia drivers (Important)

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

# Note this might remove your cuda installation as well
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Download the required driver from [Nvidia website](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/)

**Install dependenices**

For Ubuntu, installing the following dependencies is enough.

1) `build-essential` -- For building the driver

2) (Optional) gcc-multilib -- For providing 32-bit support

3) `dkms` -- For providing dkms support

As a summary, All the above packages can be installed using this command `sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc-multilib dkms`

**Create Backlist for Nouveau driver**

Create a file at `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf` with the following contents:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

Then,

for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, reboot the computer;

for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, excute `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot the computer;

**Stop lightdm/gdm/kdm**

After the computer is rebooted. We need to stop the desktop manager before excuting the runfile to install the driver. `lightdm` is the default desktop manager in Ubuntu. If GNOME or KDE desktop environment is used, installed desktop manager will then be `gdm` or `kdm`.

For Ubuntu 14.04 / 16.04, excuting `sudo service lightdm sto`p (or use gdm or kdm instead of lightdm)

For Ubuntu 16.04, excuting `sudo systemctl stop lightdm` (or use gdm or kdm instead of lightdm)

**Excuting the Runfile**

Enter the tty and enter these commands to execute the file

```
cd ~
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.69.run
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.69.run --dkms -s
```

These errors can be safe to ignore

```
WARNING: nvidia-installer was forced to guess the X library path '/usr/lib' and X module path '/usr/lib/xorg/modules'; these paths were not queryable from the system.  If X fails to find the NVIDIA X driver module, please install the `pkg-config` utility and the X.Org SDK/development package for your distribution and reinstall the driver.
```

**Check the Installation**

After a succesful installation, `nvidia-smi` command will report all your CUDA-capable devices in the system.

Hope this helps

PS: It won't stay after a kernel update.

Comment: This is a very bad advice to install Nvidia drivers form a run file. It won't stay after a kernel update. Lot's of other problems may arise. This is wrong for Ubuntu.

Comment: I just edited the source information. Have a look.

Comment: Anyway this is a real bad advice.

Comment: I must try. Eveything is done untill this moment: Create a file at /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf

Comment: bash: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf:  There is no file or catalog

Comment: Create a file `blacklist-nouveau.conf` using `vim` or `nano`. 

`vim blacklist-nouveau.conf` or `nano blacklist-nouveau.conf`

Comment: @GIX2000 If you really blacklist nouveau, you won't be able to boot at all. You are warned. Why doing all crap newbies would write?

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: @GIX2000 I had the same issue installing nvidia drivers. I installed it through this. I think I didn't create  the file `blacklist-nouveau.conf`. (skipped that step). If you are out of options, give it a try.

Comment: Ok. So I'll try without blacklist and  we  will see what hapens.

Comment: So I stopped the lightdm and in tty1 I tried to install drivers. But there is error: "Unable to determinate the path to install." I used cd ~but inside tty1 this sign (~) is written above of the row not in the middle. Could be a couse of error ? Or maby I should give a path into the place when NVIDIA-drivers are download (Home).

Comment: copy the executable to home. `cd ~` takes you to home directory. Executable I mean the file which you have downloaded from NVIDIA website.

Comment: Ok but inside tty the sign ~is written above the line not in the middle.

Comment: Or you can just do `cd`. It will also takes you to home directory

Comment: I guess you need to remove that `nouveau.modeset=0`

Comment: Nope. Dont run. Safe mode also.

Comment: I add one picture more with gnu nano 4.8. After canceling nouveau. Modeset=0.